# Query en MongoDB - Aggregate con match/group

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, nosql

Estoy realizando un ejercico que dice lo siguiente:

**Para la colección Grupos_usuarios,  encontrar las ciudades que tengan
más de 15 miembros con más de 35 años. Listar las ciudades encontradas
por nombre descendiente de miembros**

La estructura de los documentos de la colección es la siguiente:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5836b919885383034437d494"),
    "Identificador" : "G-3455",
    "Miembros" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5836b916885383034437d23b"),
            "Nombre" : "Ismael",
            "Email" : "inavarretebolsa@hotmail.es",
            "Edad" : 26,
            "País" : "España",
            "Tipo" : "Usuario individual",
            "Apellidos" : "Navarrete Bolsa",
            "Teléfono" : 636453478,
            "Ciudad" : "Logroño",
            "Identificador" : "U-3489",
            "Información_creación" : {
                "Fecha_creación" : {
                    "Mes" : 3,
                    "Día" : 22,
                    "Año" : 2016
                },
                "Hora_creación" : {
                    "Hora" : 7,
                    "Minutos" : 32,
                    "Segundos" : 20
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5836b916885383034437d227"),
            "Nombre" : "Alberto",
            "Email" : "aretiroperez@hotmail.es",
            "Edad" : 33,
            "País" : "España",
            "Tipo" : "Usuario individual",
            "Apellidos" : "Retiro Pérez",
            "Teléfono" : 615234789,
            "Ciudad" : "Barcelona",
            "Identificador" : "U-3469",
            "Información_creación" : {
                "Fecha_creación" : {
                    "Mes" : 6,
                    "Día" : 23,
                    "Año" : 2016
                },
                "Hora_creación" : {
                    "Hora" : 12,
                    "Minutos" : 12,
                    "Segundos" : 12
                }
            }
        }, <----- y sigue añadiendo miembros hasta encontrar otro `ObjectId`.
```

El caso es que he empezado a hacer la query como sigue:

```
#Utilizo una pipeline aggregate
db.getCollection('Grupos_usuarios').aggregate([

#Filtro los miembros con una edad mayor que 35
{$match:{"Miembros.Edad":{$gt:35}}},

#Mi intención aquí es agrupar los miembros por ciudad y contarlos.
{$group:{_id:"$Miembros.Ciudad",total:{$sum:1}}}]).pretty()
```

Obtengo los siguientes resultados:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : [ 
        "Sevilla", 
        "Pamplona", 
        "Toledo", 
        "Salamanca", 
        "Zaragoza"
    ],
    "total" : 1.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : [ 
        "Logroño", 
        "Barcelona", 
        "Valencia", 
        "Barcelona", 
        "Toledo"
    ],
    "total" : 5.0
}
```

No acabo de entender bien estos resutados y me hace pensar que no lo estoy haciendo bien. Además no sé como implementar la condición de mayor que 15 en el recuento de miembros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los resultados que obtienes es la agrupación de todas las ciudades de cada documento, añadiendo el total, que es igual a la longitud del array de "Miembros.Ciudad".

En base a la solución que he encontrado, tu consulta estaba bien encaminada, yo le he agregado unas etapas mas la cual te muestro aquí abajo:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Miembros" // Descomponemos el Array en objectos individuales
  },
  {
    $match: { // Filtramos
      "Miembros.Edad": { $gt: 35 }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: { // Agrupamos por la ciudad y contamos
      _id: "$Miembros.Ciudad",
      total: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { // Ordenamos de orden Descendente
      "total": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 15 // Limitamos
  }
])
```

Espero poder ayudarte con tu consulta, cualquier cosa no dudes en preguntar.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Aunque ya tienes una muy buena respuesta, yo te daré otra de acuerdo a lo que entiendo de tu pregunta:

> *Listar las ciudades que tengan más de 15 miembros con edad mayor o igual a 35 años*

Por lo tanto puede haber ninguna, una o más de una ciudad que cumplan esta característica, lo cual me lleva a plantear el siguiente proceso de agregación.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo primero es descomponer el `array` llamado `Miembros` para poder filtrar los documentos que cumplan la propiedad de *edad* mayor o igual a *35*, después podemos ordenar los documentos de forma descendiente según el campo `Miembros.nombre`, seguidamente agrupamos los datos por ciudad y por último filtramos las ciudades cuyos elementos sean mayor o igual a 15.

```js
db.grupos.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Miembros"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "Miembros.edad": {
        "$gte": 35
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "Miembros.nombre": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Miembros.ciudad",
      "Miembros": {
        "$push": {
          "nombre": "$Miembros.nombre"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gte": [
          {
            "$size": "$Miembros"
          },
          15
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Tal vez la última etapa es la que explica lo que pretendemos hacer: *devolver* las ciudades cuyos integrantes en edad mayor o igual a 35 años sean en total 15 o más de 15.

Recordemos que se puede dar el caso en que ninguna ciudad tenga esa cantidad de *miembros*, lo cual indica que la consulta no devuelva resultados.

La última etapa básicamente hace un `match` sobre los documentos cuyo `array` de *nombres* tenga una cantidad de elementos mayor o igual a 15. Para ello se usa el operador [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) que devuelve la cantidad de elementos del valor pasado de tipo `array`.

El operador [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) permite realizar el cálculo, mediante el operador [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/), comparando el tamaño del `array` *nombres* con el valor 15. Esta *expresión* devolverá `true` o `false` de acuerdo a si el `array` tiene 15 o más elementos o no.

El operador `$match` descartará entonces todos los documentos cuya *expresión* calculada devuelve `false`.

En el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Eo5oUNov7RO) puedes ver un ejemplo de esta implementación. Donde se generan 10 grupos diferentes, cada 1 con un `array` de 30 miembros, en edades comprendidas entre 30 y 50 años, y con hasta 15 diferentes ciudades de procedencia. El resultado al correr el proceso de aggregación es de sólo 6 ciudades, de las 15 involucradas, que contienen 15 o más miembros con 35 o más años de edad.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Para el ejercicio que estáis tratando de resolver, hay dos pegas, en la primera respuesta limita la salida a 15 no a que haya más de 15 miembros por ciudad, y en la segunda, que modificando un par de cosas, quedaría limitar la salida y que no pinte todos los nombres de los miembros de la siguiente forma:

```
db.Grupos_usuarios.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Miembros"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "Miembros.Edad": {
        "$gte": 35
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "total": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Miembros.Ciudad",    
        "Miembros": {
        "$push": {
          "nombre": "$Miembros.Nombre"
        }
      },
      "total":{ $sum:1}
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gte": [
          {
            "$size": "$Miembros"
          },
          15
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project":{
        "_id" : 1,
        "total":1
    }
  }
]);
```

Añadiendo la sentencia project podemos pintar justo lo que necesitamos.

Un saludo!